# Overlaying top and bottom editable caption over an image with wrapping text

Tags: android, android-layout

I wasted an entire weekend trying to do what should have been a very simple task. I just want to have an ImageView and two EditText elements overlaying it - one centered at the top, one at the bottom (acting like captions). When the text in either of the boxes is edited, it should wrap when it reaches the end of the image (captions should never overflow the image itself).
I found a million examples, but every each one of them sets `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on the root view meaning that the image absolutely has to fit the view perfectly (which is IMHO a ridiculous assumption) or else the caption will appear outside the image. In my case, I do not know the size of the image in advance as the image is dynamically chosen.

This is what I have so far:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:scaleType="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/caption_top"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"

        android:text="Top caption" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/caption_bottom"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:text="Bottom caption" />

</FrameLayout>
```

As expected, this shows the captions at the top and bottom of the screen, not ImageView.
I've tried dynamically resizing the FrameLayout like this:

```
final View frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);
        frame.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                frame.getLayoutParams().width = editedImage.getWidth();
                frame.getLayoutParams().height = editedImage.getHeight();
                frame.requestLayout();
            }
        });
```

This does force the captions to the inside of the image, but breaks a lot of other things (no element is centered any more) and somehow entered text still does not wrap, even though it's set to fill_parent and parent's width is set explicitly to match the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the ImageView and two TextViews inside a RelativeLayout (basically the XML structure you have now, but the `<FrameLayout>` element is changed to a `<RelativeLayout>`).

- The RelativeLayout:

  - `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` of `WRAP_CONTENT`
  - `android:layout_gravity` of `center_horizontal`.
- The ImageView:

  - `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` of `WRAP_CONTENT`
- The top TextView:

  - `android:layout_width` of `0dp`
  - `android:layout_height` of `WRAP_CONTENT`
  - `android:layout_alignTop` of `@id/selectedImage`
  - `android:layout_alignLeft` of `@id/selectedImage`
  - `android:layout_alignRight` of `@id/selectedImage`
  - `android:gravity` of `center_horizontal|top`
- The bottom TextView is the same as the top TextView, except aligned and gravity'd to the image bottom.
- Remove the ViewTreeObserver.

You may have to put the entire thing inside a FrameLayout to get the RelativeLayout to be centered horizontally.